Creating a separate table from existing table in PowerBI
I think this is a simple question, I'm just not sure how to go about doing it. In PowerBI, I have the below as an example, which are two time series':



Date
Series1
Series2




1-May
0.650239
0.994032


2-May
0.689518
0.457408


3-May
0.969402
0.863187


4-May
0.812362
0.547719


5-May
0.760445
0.717409


6-May
0.342214
0.091408


7-May
0.985581
0.066404


8-May
0.236865
0.507268


9-May
0.744359
0.803286


10-May
0.470509
0.221594


11-May
0.487833
0.648442


12-May
0.541049
0.143225


13-May
0.041194
0.335399


14-May
0.191586
0.951685



As I've tried to demonstrate, both of the series' are in the same table. All I'm trying to do is create a separate table which includes the most recent value and average for each series, something like the below:




Latest
Average




Series1
0.191586
0.56594


Series2
0.951685
0.52489



I tried pivoting and unpivoting in PowerQuery, but can't seem to put it in the right format. Can someone please advise on how to go about creating the separate table? I was originally thinking I'd have to create a separate measure for each calculation, but even then couldn't figure out how to format according to what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks very much.

unpivoting the table is the right approach (creating a separate table is a bad idea). What specifically didn't work when you unpivoted the data?

Apologies. I didn't mean it didn't work, it just wasn't what i was looking for. Not to go into too much detail, but I'm basically trying to come up with a summary table that includes various stats (most recent, average, etc...) for a time series. But I wanted it to be structured in a separate table so as not to play around with/edit the original table that includes the time series itself.

This will add two more tables to your model, but it works.
First, you need to unpivot your table as new table.
Then create new table using this code:
    TableSummarized =
SUMMARIZE (
    'TableUnpivot',
    'TableUnpivot'[Attribute],
    "Latest",
        CALCULATE (
            AVERAGE ( 'TableUnpivot'[Value] ),
            'TableUnpivot'[Date] = MAX ( 'TableUnpivot'[Date] )
        ),
    "Average", AVERAGE ( 'TableUnpivot'[Value] )
)

The result is:


Awesome, thank you! I'm going to try it out!

This worked like a charm, thanks again. Last question...If I wanted to add another metric, a percentile, for example, would I be able to just add that within the summarize statement?

Yes, you can add more columns with different aggregations following this logic. As you can see in this summarize statement you first give your column a name, and then you add the measure to calculate it, and it will add it as column in the table. It is a wonderful function.
